# How to add a shortcode that creates an adjacent column of text in the content editor?

Tags: shortcode, editor, content

I'd like to enable a shortcode toolbar button, similar to the "More" break, that I can click to mark an insertion point where the text should be broken into columns.

Do shortcodes have encapsulation or would I need to enter an endpoint?

Example:

```
[column]The column starts here[/column]
```

Or

```
[columnBegin]The column starts here[columnEnd]
```

I'm looking for some examples or plugins that might make this possible.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes

Answer (score 1):

Shortcode do have encapsulation. Read more about that here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

What I did was take the values with attr , then with the explode function of php make an array and then loop through it.